# CNN Image Segmentation - Train Loss decreasing but Val Loss constant?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

my U-Net train_dice_loss is decreasing but my val_dice_loss remains at 0.4. It looks like the network is overfitting but shouldn't val_dice_loss increase at some point?

[image: Tensorboard after 600th Epoch]

The network is based on the Carvana Segmentation Competition ([Colab Carvana Segmentation](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/outreach/blogs/segmentation_blogpost/image_segmentation.ipynb)). I use the same model, target function and data augmentation pipeline, but I've got much less data (~1900 Images a 256x256px). I split my data into a Training, Validation and Test-Set. On the Test Set my model predicts quite well (~ average dice_coeff 0.75) but I can't explain this graph.

Additional Information:

```
def dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred):
 smooth = 1.
 # Flatten
 y_true_f = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1])
 y_pred_f = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1])
 intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
 score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f) + 
 tf.reduce_sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
return score

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
 loss = 1 - dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred)
 return loss

def bce_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
 loss = losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) + dice_loss(y_true, y_pred)
 return loss
```

I also tried different Splits and Keras Optimizer. It always ends at ~ 0.4.

Comment: Did you try to add Dropout, reduce complexity (number of neurons) and change the optimizer and learning rate (reduce) of your U-Net model?

Comment: I halved the default learning rate of Keras Adam (lr=0.001 to 0.0005) but same result. But I will try to add Dropout and to reduce model complexity. Thank you

Comment: Are validation and training the same size? Same range?

Comment: Yes, same size (256x256px) and both sets scaled by *(1/255)